# Nuxt.js: is it possible use custom page names in Pre Rendering option?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, prerender, generate

i am currently working in a Nuxt.js project and i'm trying the Pre Rendering option. I would like to change the format name of the files created when i launch `nuxt generate`... but i don't really now if this is even possible.

If my pages folder has these 2 componentes:

```
pages\
 - page1.vue
 - page2.vue
```

the default situation is that my `dist` folder will have these files after the `generate` command:

```
dist\
 - page1
   - index.html
 - page2
   - index.html
```

Would be possible to have this structure?:

```
dist\
 - page1.html
 - page2.html
```

I've tried to create my own `router.js` with my custom paths, using `@nuxtjs/router module` and it works in dev mode, but when i try to generate the static files, there are no errors... but it doesn't work. No page files in dist folder.

Perhaps i'm missing something, or perhaps it is not possible to do this, but... has anyone faced this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Add [`generate.subFolders`](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate/#subfolders) false in your nuxt config:

```
generate: {
  subFolders: false
}
```